# Javascript DOM Invalid Pointer Error

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic

I'm having some weird issues with dynamically populating a table in Javascript. Behold the following:

```
/**
* Create dynamic table and populate column names
*/
function createTableHeaders() {
    var table = document.getElementById("list-contain").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(row);
    var th;
    for(var i=0; i<columns.length; i++) {
        th = document.createElement('th');
        th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(columns[i]));
        table.rows[0].appendChild(th);
    }
}
```

Where "columns" is an array of text strings populated in another section of my code. I'm encountering very specific symptoms:

1. The table is being populated correctly, iterating through all the items in the "columns" array.
2. I'm getting different errors in Firebug (debugger for Firefox) and IE9.

In Firefox, I'm getting a NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER on nsIDOMHTMLTableSectionElement.appendChild.

In Internet Explorer 9, I'm getting two errors:

1. SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by javascript:void(0)
2. SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3)

I *think* the first IE error is related to something else in my code, but I have no clue why Firefox and IE are giving me different DOM errors. The table is still being populated correctly in both browsers, I can't tell why they're throwing these errors yet executing the code correctly.

If anyone has experience/insight in these matters, I would much appreciate the help! :)

Comment: I created a quick test page and did not have a problem when I ran your code. The columns were appended without a problem. Are you sure the error is inside that function?

Comment: Did you point to that function using a `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="createTableHeaders()">…` or something like this? That's deprecated, use hyperlinks only to point to other (parts of the) pages.

Comment: Don't `<th>` elements have to go in a `<tr>` that's in the `<thead>` and not the `<tbody>`?

Comment: Patorjk, the columns are appended, but if you open a debugger, you will notice exceptions being thrown.

Comment: Marcel, I don't believe so, but I'm still looking around for the source of that error.

Comment: Pointy, good point, I didn't think of that; HTML may allow it (hence the table still displays) but Javascript DOM may realize that <th> belongs in <thead> and throws an exception when I add it to <tbody>. I'm taking a look; please submit your suggestion as an answer so I can recognize it. :)

Comment: TheDramaLlama, you can vote up Pointy's comment, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved; the syntax I was using was correct, it turns out another script that I was using to sort the table was bugging out. The table was originally static HTML, and when I generated it using Javascript, the sorting script broke. :)